# Need to go back to main view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

Can you help me, I got a navigationbar, with a back button, when I press the back button I want to go back to my view, but not sure it's the correct way, I'm doing it.

```cs
public void Login()
    {
        cmdLogin.TouchUpInside += delegate {

            var rootViewController = new UINavigationController();
            LoginViewController LVC = new LoginViewController();
            rootViewController.PushViewController(LVC, false);

            this._window.RootViewController = rootViewController;
            this._window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
            _backButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, onBackSelected);

            LVC.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = _backButton;
            LVC.Title = "Login";

        };

    }
```

and my onBackSelected looks like this.

```cs
private void onBackSelected(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            _window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            viewController = new CirkelWithButtonsViewController (_window);
            _window.RootViewController = viewController;
            _window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
        }
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to go back? please provide a better solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NavigationController.PopToViewController (yourViewController, true);
```

is the translation of @jitendra-deore answer to xamarin.iOS `C#`

Comment: When i do that, i get an error: No overload Method "PopToViewController" takes 1 arguments 
I tried:        NavigationController.PopToViewController (viewController);

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `animated` argument. Fixed in place.

Comment: I get a new error now, Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: viewController

Comment: I also get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I get that error when i press back in my navigationController, the other error I get when i Login and i call the method "GoBackToView()"

Comment: My viewController I just set a
        CirkelWithButtonsViewController viewController;
I don't know if this is a correct way to do this?

Comment: You have to instantiate object(viewController) before you use it.
If you type CirkelWithButtonsViewController viewController; it's just declared but it's still null.
If you type CirkelWithButtonsViewController viewController = new CirkelWithButtonsViewController(); it instantiate it and you will have it working.

Comment: When I do that, I get the erorr: "The type 'CirkelWithButtons.CirkelWithButtonsViewController' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments". I think it want a UIWindow as parameter, but when I do that, I get an error saying it can't pop to a view that doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried `NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);` that doesn't help either.

Comment: I get a new error now, I created `UIWindow _window = new UIWindow();` and then i did `CirkelWithButtonsViewController viewController = new CirkelWithButtonsViewController(_window);` and it says "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method or property 'CirkelWithButtons.LoginViewController._window'

Answer (score 0):

```
   navigationController.PopToViewController(yourViewController);
```

Try this one..

Comment: Yea if you can make a solution in Xamarin, that would be great like @Amar said.

Comment: Doesn't work, if you could look at the comments i made at @Stephane-Delcroix post, and see if you can make answer out of that, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```